# No Parameters are listed in URL using OrkestraGuzzleBundle

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, guzzle

While using Symfony2 [OrkestraGuzzleBundle](https://github.com/orkestra/OrkestraGuzzleBundle) I cannot make it to work with path parameters properly.

Here is my command function:

```
/**
 * @Command(name="nitex_authenticate", method="GET", uri="/oauth/v2/token?client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials")
 * @Doc("Get Access Token")
 * @Param(name="client_id", type="string", required="true")
 * @Param(name="client_secret", type="string", required="true")
 */
public function getNitexAccessTokenCommand()
{
    return $this->getResponse();
}
```

When I execute the command I receive "Bad Request" error message with URL shown as [url] `http://niksites.localapps.com/oauth/v2/token?client_id=&client_secret=&grant_type=client_credentials`

```
$authParams = array (
    'client_id'     => '1_3rshkkbo2c00c8ws0sswwow4co8ckkgog0oocows0coswwc44w',
    'client_secret' => '45j81mlc70iswgg0sgscgg04s4soc8wow8wos8sww0ccwggoks'
);
$response = $this->guzzle
    ->getService('nitex.auth')
    ->execute('nitex_authenticate', $authParams);
```

What am I doing wrong? Seems to be pretty straight forward based on the documentation however it does not work for me for some reason.

Comment: Apparently it is a defect of this bundle - found the same issue described at https://github.com/orkestra/OrkestraGuzzleBundle/issues/55 . Let me know if someone has workaround for this.

Comment: Have not found the solution for the issue described above however tried to use alternative bundle from https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle and it looks and works really well.